# Javascript new Function only working in browser

Tags: javascript, function

my code:

```
function number(a){

return a
}

function x() {
    return new Function("return number('22')")()
}
console.log(x())
```

I am experimenting with calling a function from a function using the new Function()()
now when running this piece of code in a browser it is working just fine but when i run it in webstorm it throws the error below:

> undefined:3
>   return number('22')
>   ^
>
> ReferenceError: number is not defined
>       at eval (eval at x (C:\Users\WebstormProjects\tests.js:11:12), :3:1)
>       at x (C:\Users\WebstormProjects\tests.js:11:47)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\WebstormProjects\tests.js:13:13)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
>       at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11

Comment: I'm guessing that it's sandboxing eval so that your number function isn't in scope. Also, obligatory warning: *never use eval or the function constructor*. There is almost no legitimate reason to ever use them ever.

Comment: The code in a `new Function()` is global-scoped, but your `number` is not

Comment: @JaredSmith No, it's just scoping the *tests.js* module. No sandboxing.

Comment: everything runs in test.js and the functions used are both just in the file they are not in any object etc